# Index out of bounds error: animation/simulation

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, indexoutofboundsexception

I can't figure out why I'm getting this index out of bounds error. I've done test prints of the values at those indices and they print out correctly. Can someone explain where exactly my array is being restructured?

```
class Particle:

    def __init__(self,fourvector = [1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0],
                 origin=(0,0)):
        self.mass = 2.5       # Mass in kg
        self.fourvector = np.asarray(fourvector,dtype='float')
        self.Vx_init = self.fourvector[2]
        self.x_init = self.fourvector[0]
        self.y_init = self.fourvector[1]
        self.Vy_init = self.fourvector[3]
        self.time_passed = 0
        self.origin = origin
        print fourvector[0]
        print fourvector[2]

    def position(self):
        x0 = self.origin[0]
        x1 = self.fourvector[0]
        Vx = self.fourvector[2]
        y0 = self.origin[1]
        y1 = self.fourvector[1]
        Vy = self.fourvector[3]
        x = x0 + x1 * Vx
        y = x0 + y1 * Vy

        return (x,y)

    def derivs(self,fourvector):
        '''derivative computation setup'''
        x_pos = fourvector[0]
        y_pos = fourvector[1]
        dydx = np.zeros_like(fourvector)
        dydx[0] = fourvector[2] #x-comp of velocity
        dydx[1] = (-x_pos)/((x_pos)**2 + (y_pos)**2)**1.5
        dydx[2] = fourvector[3] #y-comp of velocity
        dydx[3] = (-y_pos)/((x_pos)**2 + (y_pos)**2)**1.5
        return dydx

    def time_step(self,dt):
        '''Time progression and state fourvector update'''
        self.fourvector = integrate.odeint(self.derivs,0,dt)
        self.time_passed += dt


body = Particle([1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0])    #Object of Particle created.
dt = 1./30

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal',autoscale_on=False,xlim=(-3,3),ylim=(-3,3))
ax.grid()

line, = ax.plot([],[],'o-',lw=2)
time_text = ax.text(0.02,0.95,'',transform=ax.transAxes)

def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    time_text.set_text('')
    return line, time_text

def animate(i):
    global body, dt
    body.time_step(dt)
    line.set_data(*body.position())
    time_text.set_text('time = %.1f' %body.time_passed)
    return line, time_text

from time import time
t0 = time()
animate(0)
t1 = time()
interval = 1000*dt - (t1 - t0)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 300,
                              interval = interval, blit=True, init_func=init)
plt.show()
```

The error traceback:

```
bash-3.2$ python MoreCrap.py 
1.0
1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MoreCrap.py", line 80, in <module>
    animate(0)
  File "MoreCrap.py", line 74, in animate
    line.set_data(*body.position())
  File "MoreCrap.py", line 26, in position
    Vx = self.fourvector[2]
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Comment: Vote to close? Why? I can't see where my indices are being rearranged, seems like a straightforward programming question to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `integrate.odeint` is wrong. Look in the manual if it really does what you think.

In any case, the `fourvector` has value `[1. 1. 1. 2.]` before the call to it and value `[[0.]]` after the call to it, so it doesn't contain any value with index `[2]`.

The manpage for odeint is [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that `integrate.odeint` issue out. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the `fourvector` going from `[1 1 1 2]` to `[[0]]` though.